# Gmail is blocking my IP from sending email, how do I test email sending from my local machine?

Tags: ruby, email

I'm writing a ruby script that sends an email. I'm using my gmail account to test if I can successfully receive the email. However I get the following error in sendmail:

```
May 15 01:03:50 Xxx-MacBook.local postfix/smtp[9801]: 0BBFE4B0D7AE: to=<xxx@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.27]:25, delay=3.2, delays=0.02/0.01/1.4/1.8, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [114.108.235.226      12] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for 550 5.7.1 more information. he5si1273541pbb.27 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I never used, but you can check this - http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html

Comment: You can use http://mailcatcher.me

Comment: You might try "Post Hoc":   https://github.com/agilepro/posthoc